# UITextField stopping shake event?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, ios

For those of you who work graphically, here is a diagram of the view hierarchy:

`Root View -> UINavigationController -> UITableView -> Edit View -> Problem UITextfield`

Basically,  `- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` gets called in my Root View when the device shakes.

When a user taps on the "edit" icon (a pen, in the bottom of the screen - not the traditional UINavigationBar edit button), the main view adds a subview to itself and animates it on to the screen using a custom animation.

This subview contains a UINavigationController which holds a UITableView. The UITableView, when a cell is tapped on, loads a subview into itself. This second subview is the culprit. For some reason, a UITextField in this second subview is causing problems.

When a user taps on the view, the main view will not respond to shakes unless the UITextField is active (in editing mode?).

*Additional info:*

**My Motion Event Handler:**

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 NSLog(@"%@", [event description]);
 SystemSoundID SoundID;
 NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shake" ofType:@"aif"];
 AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &SoundID);
 AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SoundID); 
 [self genRandom:TRUE];
}
```

**The `genRandom:` Method:**

```
/* Generate random label and apply it */
-(void)genRandom:(BOOL)deviceWasShaken{
 if(deviceWasShaken == TRUE){
  decisionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: (@"%@", [shakeReplies objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % [shakeReplies count])])];
 }else{
  SystemSoundID SoundID;
  NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"string" ofType:@"aif"];
  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &SoundID);
  AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SoundID);
  decisionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: (@"%@", [pokeReplies objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % [pokeReplies count])])];
 }
}
```

`shakeReplies` and `pokeReplies` are both NSArrays of strings. One is used for when a certain part of the screen is poked and one is for when the device is shaken.  The app will randomly choose a string from the NSArray and display onscreen.

As always, code samples are appreciated. *I've added my own to help explain the problem.*

Comment: How is the keyboard in a subview?

Comment: No longer relevant, please close.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard: Look for `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert`

As for the shake detection. Once the `UITextField` resigns first responder (not in focus, keyboard hidden), you need to make sure another `UIResponder` in the chain becomes firstResponder. For example, if you have a button that sends `-resignFirstResponder` to the text field, you'll need to do this:

```
- (IBAction)pressButton {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This did its job and was posted first. Incomplete answer though.

Answer (score 1):

try using `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

and for key board to be glassy use:

```
[textfield setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks,
Madhup

Comment: The first method is a convenience method on what I was trying. Nothing doing there, didn't work.